# Rename all values in column pandas base a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have this list of lists = `[['Lost Summoner Kitty', 70], ['Ironbound', 4000]]`

And I also have this dataframe:

[image]

I would like to find a general way to replace item_id integer by his name that is present in the previous list

Comment: Can you post the DF in text format?

Comment: Turn the list into a dictionary, then you can use the `map()` operation on pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Turn the list of lists into a dictionary where the IDs are the keys. Then use that in `pandas.Series.map()` to convert the `item_id` columns.

```
mapping = dict(map(reversed, list_of_lists))
df.item_id = df.item_id.map(mapping)
```

Comment: Is it still working if my first list contains an element that is not in the dataframe ?

Comment: Yes. You're iterating through the dataframe, not the list. It won't work if the df contains IDs that aren't in the list -- those IDs will be replaced with `NaN`. You could use `apply()` if you want more control.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `dict` from the `list` and then use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on the created `dict`.

```
lst = [['Lost Summoner Kitty', 70], ['Ironbound', 4000]]
dct = {num: entry for entry, num in lst}
# dct -> {70: 'Lost Summoner Kitty', 4000: 'Ironbound'}

df['item_id'] = df['item_id'].map(dct)
```

Comment: Can use iterable unpacking: `{num: entry for entry, num in lst}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
df['item_name'] = [dict([l[::-1] for l in lists]).get(i, None) 
                                 for i in df['item_id']]
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)
  steam_id  item_id            item_name
0      XXX       70  Lost Summoner Kitty
1      YYY     4000            Ironbound
```